# Move every folder to top level including content recursively in Powershell

Tags: powershell, recursion, scripting

how do I recursively move all directories to the top level including all their sub directories.
The files in the directories should be copied as well.
And if a directory already exists its contents should be merged and all the files should remain (maybe via renaming the files)

**e.g.**

```
dir1
----img1
----img2
----dir2
--------img1
--------img2
------------dir1
------------img1
------------img2
------------img3
dir4
----img1
----img2
----img3
```

**becomes**

```
dir1
----img1
----img1_1
----img2
----img2_2
----img3
dir2
----img1
----img2
dir4
----img1
----img2
----img3
```

My approach was something like that.

```
Get-ChildItem $SOURCE_PATH  -Recurse |
            Foreach-Object {
                $IS_DIR = Test-Path -Path $_.FullName -PathType Container
                if ($IS_DIR) {
                    Move-Item $_.FullName -dest ($DESTPATH + "/" + $_.Name)
                }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of moving directories I would move individual files to have control over destination name of each file.

This code is untested, it is just intended to give you an idea. Tweak as needed.

```
# Use parameter -File to operate on files only
Get-ChildItem $SOURCE_PATH -File -Recurse | Foreach-Object {

    # Get name of parent directory
    $parentDirName = $_.Directory.Name

    # Make full path of destination directory
    $destSubDirPath = Join-Path $DESTPATH $parentDirName

    # Create destination directory if not exists (parameter -Force).
    # Assignment to $null to avoid unwanted output of New-Item
    $null = New-Item $destSubDirPath -ItemType Directory -Force 

    # Make desired destination file path. First try original name.
    $destFilePath = Join-Path $destSubDirPath $_.Name

    # If desired name already exists, append a counter until we find an unused name.
    $i = 1
    while( Test-Path $destFilePath ) {
        # Create a new name like "img1_1.png"
        $destFilePath = Join-Path $destSubDirPath "$($_.BaseName)_$i.$($_.Extension)"
        $i++
    }

    # Move and possibly rename file.
    Move-Item $_ $destFilePath 
}
```